# What happens to DNS queries in adhoc network?

Tags: networking, dns, adhoc, mdns

I have an adhoc network where A uses B as an HTTP/S proxy.  A has no direct internet access, but can access the internet through B.  I have it up and running just fine, but can only access websites via IP address.  Whenever I try to use a domain name I'm told the host is unknown.  From what I've read, computers use mDNS in adhoc mode vs regular DNS which is probably why I don't see any DNS requests when I run `nslooup` in adhoc mode.

So how do I go about resolving domain names in a adhoc network?  If I could forward the DNS queries to server B that would be great, but it doesn't even appear that client A preforms DNS queries in adhoc mode.  Is there a way to resolve all domain names to server B, and have B parse the packets for the requested domain and preform the DNS query from there?

Answer (score 0):

DNS is not run over HTTP. Manually setup B as your default gateway, that should solve your IP routing problem. Then configure the DNS to some outside DNS server, like 8.8.8.8. That should take care of it.